# Magnetic loss of steel

Tags: loss, resistivity

The software called gprMax which simulates EM waves in varying environments. I am trying to enter steel has material but from the picture, it also requires the magnetic loss(ohm/meter). But I have been searching for this property on the internet and cannot find anything. Can someone please assist?

I am trying to simulate the behaviour of the EM radiation inside a steel container. A rfid tag is mounted on a plastic rfid mount and the tag is affixed to it. Various materials are then placed infront of the RFID tag such has steel, wood and plastic. I got all the parameters for plastic and wood. I just need the magnetic loss of steel. The receiver then picks up the E and H fields from which I calculated the power received from the tag at that point.

This is shown in the picture

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ThePhoton why does not the internet show the properties of material like steel with  their magnetic loss (ohms/meter) properties? Can you assist in calculating this property?

Comment: Magnetic losses are very sensitive to composition and heat treatment, so are only given for finished components like magnetic cores.

Comment: @Neil_UK so there is no table of a list of materials and their respective magnetic losses on the internet?

Comment: Do you mean hysteresis losses, or are you including eddy current losses in your "magnetic losses" category?

Comment: @TimWescott this software only says that I must enter the magnetic loss in ohms/meter. I attach a picture

Comment: Conduction or radiated fields?

Comment: Specific companies that make ferrite cores (Fair-Rite does a pretty good job, if you dig for it) will list magnetic loss parameters for specific materials -- but that's because the materials are engineered for use in magnetics.  You *may* also be able to find tables of characteristics for steels that are designed for use in magnetics, but they'll be general, and will have to include the sort of heat-treatment that's been applied, as @Neil_UK points out.

Comment: I see no picture -- try editing your question again?  Or maybe you didn't push the "save changes" button?  Tell us what "the software" is?  Someone is vastly simplifying something -- eddy current losses are proportional to frequency, and hysteresis losses are both proportional to frequency and are nonlinear to the applied magnetic field.

Comment: @TimWescott I have edited it.

Comment: Please include **the name of this mysterious** "the software" **that you are using**.  Because it is *vastly oversimplifying the problem* and *probably should not be trusted*.

Comment: @TimWescott the software is called is gprMax is stated in the question

Comment: @TimWescott I have provided you with the name of the software, at least followup from there. If you are not interested then inform me, so I can stop monitoring this site for a reply.

Comment: "the software is called is gprMax is stated in the question" -- my apologies, I missed that.

Comment: The "gpr" in "gprMax" stands for "ground penetrating radar".  What are you attempting to use it for that you're using steel as a material?

Comment: @TimWescott I have updated the question to give a better understanding. The steel container are the containers used in shipping or transporting goods on roads. The gprMax software is not only used for ground-penetrating radar but can also be adapted for my case as shown in the picture.